# Host a static Blazor Application

Tags: azure, deployment, hosting, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am looking for a hosting service for my Blazor Server web application. It is a simple static website with some extensions to send emails and styling but there is no database or API project currently.

I looked into Godaddy but looks like it does not provide hosting. Also I tried to host it on Netlify but it did not work and there are no tutorials or support fo .Net Core 3.1.

What would be the best place to host a simple blazor app? I am trying to find a cheaper option than Azure

Comment: Azure Static Web Apps is free during preview

Comment: @CSharpRocks Thank you! Do you know if it supports Blazor Server Hosting model or does it only support Blazor Web assembly?
Mine is Blazor server because I have a email functionality on some forms using MailKit and it does not work with web assembly

Comment: Static hosts support only SPA like applications like React, Angular, Blazor WebAssembly. For server side blazor you are going to need a hosting service. I would look for a cheap Linux server and deploy there.

Comment: You can deploy to a free Heroku Dyno using https://github.com/Aguafrommars/dotnetcore-buildpack as I do with [TheIdServer](https://theidserver.herokuapp.com)

Comment: @aguafrommars Can you help me with hosting? I can pay you if you do freelancing?

Comment: You can sponsor me. let's continue on github. Open issue please

Comment: @aguafrommars I do not see an issues tab on your github link. Email me learnaspnet715@gmail.com